# Apache htaccess SetHandler

Tags: apache-2.2

How can I disable SetHandler directive? 
It is a legacy apache2.2 server, AllowOverrideList not working here. 
I can't use AllowOverride None, because I need mod_rewrite.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Simply reading the documentation for the `AllowOverride` directive would have told you exactly what you need: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

However in the spirit of not just pasting links. You need to set `AllowOverride` so that it does not include the `FileInfo` option as this is the option that enables `SetHandler` to be used in htaccess files. This will of course disable all the other directives listed under this option. There is no way to do this at a more granular level.